# How does Windows determine dll address when using loadlibrary

Tags: windows, dll, virtual-memory

First, sorry for my bad english.

I'm trying to make emulator to emulating PE binary with unicorn emulator.
My goal is place every dll in emulator that PE needed and hook some specific APIs.

What I am curious about is how the dll listed in PE's IAT is palced in virtual memory when the PE is loaded, and additionally how it is placed when the PE loads a new module through LoadLibrary.

I wanna make some good argorithm for dll placing, but I'm struggling because I have no knowledge about about algorithms or dll placement.

I hope for your guide. thank you.

Comment: This related question on SO has some more details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72413668/150978